# Search and view data from external database

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, database

I have a business requirement to create a way for users to search and view results from an external database (Snowflake) in Salesforce. 
I have created a simple visualforce page and need to send a query to Snowflake searching for a match on the searchString captured in my page using one of their JDBC/ODBC drivers on click of 'Search' button.

I think I have to create a webservice and expose the REST API however I am unsure how to use the appropriate Snowflake driver.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I think you need to contact Snowflake support to get proper information

Comment: I have discussed this with Snowflake and they have referred me to their Driver documentation as they have said I need to use one of their drivers in order to gain access and take care of sessions etc however this is not getting me very far. I am not sure how to use/reference the driver in a class.

Comment: What you will need is an API from Snowflake so that you can connect from Salesforce (your VF page). JDBC/ODBC driver is mostly used for fat clients and this will be of no help in your case as they need to be downloaded on local machine and then utilized accordingly (its a jar file necessarily here). As far as I can lookup, seems they do have the REST API support but its case to case basis, refer to this [link](https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00007wNfYXSA0/is-there-documentation-for-the-rest-http-api-to-connect-to-snowflake), so you should definitely reach out to them.

Comment: Thanks Jayant, I have discussed the use of the API with Snowflake however due to all the requirements for spinning up a session, logging in and teardown along with the the actual query they advise not to use it and this is why it is a case by case basis. With this in mind, I will see if I can satisfy business requirements without connecting to Snowflake.